# printf and echo -e are giving different results

Tags: ubuntu, echo, escape-characters, printf, ascii

I am using `\0n` escape sequence with `echo -e` and `printf` where n is the octal value of the ASCII character to be printed. When i used the statement `echo -e "\0101"` the shell is printing character `A` but when i use `printf "\0101"` the shell is printing `1` which is the Least significant bit of the octal number i provided but if i remove `0` in the starting and use the command as `printf "\101"` it is correctly printing `A` as expected. so my doubt is why there is such a difference for this particular escape sequence, i tried for many other escape sequences but they gave same results with both echo and printf.I am using `Ubuntu` and currently working on `bash`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man echo`<sup>1</sup>:

> `\0NNN`  byte with octal value `NNN` (1 to 3 digits)

From `man printf`<sup>1</sup>:

> `\NNN`   byte with octal value `NNN` (1 to 3 digits)

The two commands are not accepting the same format for octal sequences.

You can easily check that their actual output is quite different:

```
$ echo -en "\0101" | od -A n -t o1
 101
```

`echo` is actually printing the intended single character `A`.

```
$ printf "\0101" | od -A n -t o1
 010 061
```

`printf`, on the other hand, is seeing `\010` as a character escape sequence and the subsequent `1` as a literal character, which is just copied to the output.
It is thus printing a `<backspace>` (which has no visible effect, being the first character of the string), whose octal representation is `010`, followed by the non-interpreted `1`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>To be precise, the commands you are running are most likely the Bash builtin ones, not those described by `man` (likely from `coreutils`). But both `help echo` and `help printf` confirm the `man`'s syntax or directly refer to it.</sub>